# Why is the Jacobian determinant of a map the reciprocal of the Jacobian determinant of the inverse map?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, determinant, jacobian

Consider a mapping $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

\begin{align}
g(u,v) &= (x, y)\\
&=(f(u,v), \;g(u, v))
\end{align}

Consider the inverse mapping $g^{-1} = \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

\begin{align}
g^{-1}(x,y) &= (u,v) \\
&= (h(x,y), \;I(x,y))
\end{align}

**Question**
Why is it that the determinant of the Jacobian of $g$ denoted as $|\text{Jac}\; g|$ equal to $1$ over the determinant of the Jacobian of $g^{-1}$ denoted $|\text{Jac}\; g^{-1}|$?

$$ |\text{Jac}\;g| = \frac{1}{|\text{Jac}\;g^{-1}|}$$
You could do the computation. But I'm not sure how I would connect the two sides of the equality. The left side is $x_uy_v - y_ux_v$. But I can't seem to get this equal to the other side.

**Thoughts**
Consider a function $y = f(x)$. Consider it's inverse function $x = f^{-1}(y)$. The two are related as follows

$$\frac{df^{-1}}{dy}\Bigg|_y = \frac{1}{\frac{df}{dx}\Big|_x} $$

where the evaluation values $x,y$ are images of one another (people write this formula in many different ways). This last equation makes intuitive sense to me. Draw a graph of $f(x)$. To find the graph of the inverse function, all you have to do is rotate this graph $90^\circ$ counterclockwise. If you draw a tangent line to the graph of $f(x)$, such an instantaneous line has some rise/run. Once you rotate the graph $90^\circ$ counterclockwise to view the inverse graph, this tangent line now has a slope of run/rise. Therefore the formula follows. Is there such an interpretation for my question? I tried writing out both determinants. However, it's not clear to me how I would related $\partial x/\partial u$ to $\partial u/\partial x$. You would think that

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\Bigg|_u = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}\Big|_x} $$

This would be true given $x = f(u)$. However we have $x = f(u,v)$ and $u = h(x,y)$ and I'm not sure of the relationship between the two. Thanks in advance

Comment: If differentiable $f,g$ satisfy $f(g(x)) = x$ for $x$ in some neighbourhood then $Df(g(x))Dg(x) = I$. Then $\det(Df(g(x))) \det g(x) = 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat Does this translate to many variable functions? $f$ and $g$ seem like functions of 1 input, then you are taking the determinant of a single input function or single input matrix in this case. If $f$ stands for a many variable input and many variable output function, I guess Df would stand for the Jacobian matrix of $f$.

Comment: Yes, $D h(x)$ is the (multivariable) derivative of $h$ evaluated at $x$. $[Dh(x)]_{ij} = {\partial h_i(x) \over \partial x_j}$.

Comment: This is part of the content of the Inverse Function Theorem. You’re assuming, by the way, that $g^{-1}$ exists, which is not in general a given.